# Step 1 of Rudin theorem 7.32 proof

Tags: real-analysis

There is one part I don't get from the proof of Baby Rudin's theorem 7.32:

[image]

The reason we require that the polynomial $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i y^i$ to vanish when $y=0$ because we want this property to hold: if $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in K$, then $g(x)=0$ as well. Is that correct?

Comment: It is required to say that $g$ is in $\mathcal B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the answer in the comments, let us suppose that the polynomial does not vanish at $0$ and see what goes wrong.

Suppose that given $\varepsilon > 0$, there are real numbers $c_{0}, \ldots , c_{n}$ such that for all $y\in [-a ,a]$,

$$\left| \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_{i} y^{i} - |y| \right| < \varepsilon ,$$

where the convention is being used that $0^{0} = 1$ in this context.

Then for all $x\in K$, $f(x)\in [-a, a]$, so it follows that for all $x\in K$,

$$ \left| \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_{i}(f(x))^{i} - |f(x)| \right| < \varepsilon .$$

If for each $i\in \{0, \ldots , n\}$ the function $f^{i}:K\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f^{i}(x) := (f(x))^{i}$, then by using that the component-wise product of two functions in $\mathscr{B}$ is again in $\mathscr{B}$, it can be shown by a finite induction argument that $f^{i} \in \mathscr{B}$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots , n\}$. Then $c_{i}f^{i} \in \mathscr{B}$ for each $i\in \{1, \ldots , n\}$, so it follows that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}f^{i}\in \mathscr{B}$.

For the case $i=0$, $f^{0}(x) = (f(x))^{0} = 1$ for each $x\in X$, so it follows that $c_{0}f^{0}$ is a constant function. However, there is no information that can be used to determine that $c_{0}f^{0}$ is in the algebra $\mathscr{B}$. If $c_{0} = 0$, then it is clear that $c_{0}f^{0}$ is in $\mathscr{B}$ because $c_{0}f^{0}$ is equal to zero times any other function in $\mathscr{B}$, which is again in $\mathscr{B}$. But in general, if the polynomial does not vanish at $0$, then $c_{0}\neq 0$ and there is not enough information to conclude that

$$g := \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_{i}f^{i} = c_{0}f^{0} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i} f^{i}$$

is in $\mathscr{B}$. However, if it is the case that $c_{0} = 0$, then it does follow that $g$ is in $\mathscr{B}$.

That is the reason why it is assumed that the polynomial vanishes at $0$, because you can use that to deduce that $g$ is in $\mathscr{B}$, whereas if it is not assumed that the polynomial vanishes at $0$, there is not enough information to conclude that $g$ is in $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: But constant functions are continuous, no?

Comment: @JohnDavies They are continuous, but you do not have the assumption that constant functions are in $\mathscr{B}$ at this stage. Remember that $\mathscr{B}$ consists of a subalgebra of continuous functions, and the statement which needs to be proved is that all continuous real-valued functions on $K$ are contained in $\mathscr{B}$.